# how to save image after given Gestures in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

This is my Transparent image (Front image).

[image]

This is my selected image (Back Image).

[image]

I am giving gestures to the back image.

**How can i save my image after using of pan, pinch, rotate gestures.**

Present am able to combine both images but back image is saving as it is like (below image)

[image]

Using this code

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(640, 960);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize);

[backImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
[frontImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];


finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finalImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

I think i should handle this two lines but i don't know how to handle.

```
 [backImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
 [frontImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
```

Can any one help me will highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: it is because u r using draw in rect for back image.

Comment: thanks for your  response,Then which method can i use ?

Comment: y don't you skip that line, as you are already drawing the image on front image

Comment: Already tried that one, if i skip that line am saving only my front image.

Comment: U should use layer to save the image. Look into screenshot the uiview

Comment: Not getting proper out put by using layer. And which screenshot can i look ?

Comment: I think am not using in proper way can you provide me some lines. am using this line "[backImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];"

Comment: Try using 2 uiview  and do what you are doing on top view, and have the reference of the back image in back view

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code to get snapshot your imageview.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourImageViewToSnapShot.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

[yourImageViewToSnapShot.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I think i should snapshot my entire view... not image view...Because i have two image views.